# Can I open a studio 2020 project someone else wrote

Tags: visual-studio

We have a project a contractor wrote in  Visual Studio 2020 cpmmunity. (C# I believe.) Im pretty sure they used Snap7 to talk to our PLC. Per the contract we were supposed to retain the source in case we needed to alter or change. I tried opening the solution a couple weeks ago and I got a login for the original developer.

Is this just a license thing because they used Community?? I understand this was something new for Studio. (I paid $400?? for a license for 2017 that year)

If so I have been experimenting with Studio Community 2022 and I created my own account, can I use this license to open and view the code?

When I saw the login I tried to contact the original developer at least a half dozen times. Apparently she doesn't work for the company any more.

Comment: What exactly is asking you to login? What service? I wouldn't expect VS to store credentials in an actual solution, unless this developer has no idea what they're doing and sent you every file (including local user config).

Comment: It's asking me to sign in to Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. If I cancel it just closes the solution. Does that mean I need a license or can I create a account and use that. I have Studio 2022 I have been experimenting with.

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what's going on here, but as I mentioned before if you're seeing it prompt for the original developer's login credentials, then you probably have a bunch of per-user settings lying around with the source code. These sorts of things should not be part of a source code bundle. For instance, you would never commit those files to source control. This includes file types like `.suo` `.sdf` `.opensdf` `.user` `.aps` `.VC.db` `.VC.opendb` or a `.vs` directory. Try making a copy of the solution, removing all that stuff and then opening it.